# How much math i need to know for data mining projects

Tags: data-mining, data-warehouse

I want to work in data warehousing and data analyst jobs. I am reading books on data mining and warehousing . But i am going mad by the techincal math stuff like probability , fourier transform and wavelet function.

I am not very good at those statistical math details.

i want to know that if i work in DW job industry then do i need to learn that stuff or things are already build on those and i don't need that math stuff

Comment: Voting to close because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 4):

Data mining is a large field. There is a lof of different data mining techniques and problems.

There is some people from statistic and math background who will use a lot of math.

But there is also people from an algorithmic, computer science or database background. Some of them will use less math.

So it depends on what you want to do in data mining.

Also if you just want to apply some algorithms, you could use some data mining tools that have already been programmed by other people so you don't need to design them by yourself.

But, in general mathematics is very strongly related to computer science.

Answer (score 1):

Data Mining was invented by computer scientists because statisticians were too busy thinking about math. They definitely dropped the ball on that one.

The books on the stats side are math focused, and the books on the computer science side are process focused.

I would start with Programming Collective Intelligence (O'Reilly), which does not have much math.

I would also check out the work of Kardi Teknomo, who shows that a lot of data mining can be done using Excel:

http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/

Answer (score 1):

To work at any high paying computer related job you will need a working knowledge of statistical math. I learned math when I turned 50 and earned my MS @ 53. I learned to program on my own with much help from You Tube. I got my first job in a "data warehouse" and now with two years experience, I am actively recruited for very good paying jobs in this field. Math requires much practice and work. But it does pay off

Comment: Thanks sam, that really gave me confidence. so it means we can learn at any age. i thought once we get old then we cant change fields

Answer (score 0):

Data-mining is heavy on statistics. To make it really work, you need to have a good understanding for what you are doing. It's easy to end up with a result that at first looks great, but then does not at all work in practise because it was for example overfitted, or in any other way not statistically valid.

Do *not* approach it from a data warehousing side. They have no idea what data mining is. To DW people, often even computing projected averages is "data mining".